# Modify Microsoft Docs PaginatedList to work with standard List (.Net Core MVC)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been trying to follow a pagination example from the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page)

I have managed to get far enough to when the method passes the `PaginatedList` to the View. However in this return statement it is complaining about the argument:

[image]

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TripTable(int? page)
{
    var trips = from t in _tripcontext.Tripmetadata select t;

    page = 1;

    int pageSize = 10;
        
    return PartialView("PartialTripsView", await PaginatedList<Tripmetadata>.CreateAsync(trips.AsNoTracking(), page ?? 1, pageSize));
}
```

I have managed to make this method work for other models, but for some reason it doesn't work for my Tripmetadata and I don't know why that is..

## Tripmetadata.cs

```
namespace MSPFrontend.Models
{
    public partial class Tripmetadata
    {
        public Tripmetadata()
        {
            Tripgpsdata = new HashSet<Tripgpsdata>();
            Tripstate = new HashSet<Tripstate>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int Tripid { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Start Timestamp")]
        public long? Starttimestamp { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "End Timestamp")]
        public long? Endtimestamp { get; set; }

        public long? Duration { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Average Speed")]
        public decimal? AvgSpeed { get; set; }

        public decimal? Distance { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tripgpsdata> Tripgpsdata { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tripstate> Tripstate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I make it work for my Tripmetadata model?

## UPDATE

I have tried modifying my PaginatedList class by adding the following (non async function), but without success:

```
public static Task<PaginatedList<T>> Create(List<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    var count = source.Count();
    var items = source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
}
```

However it now complains that it cannot:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'MSPFrontend.Data.PaginatedList<T>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MSPFrontend.Data.PaginatedList<T>>'
```

Comment: Do you have a second class named Tripmetadata? The error implies the two lists are of different types.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see your code before the update, but you appear to be mixing async and sync actions. Try the following code in your PaginatedList, and keep the rest of your example code the same.

Changes to note: (1) Everything is async now. (2) Your return type should be an `IQueryable<T>`

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    // ... cutting out irrelevant code
    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize) {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. However I already had this piece of code, as implied by the link in the top to the Microsoft Docs.